# Multiple http requests on the same long running operation with Sinatra and EventMachine

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, sinatra, httprequest, eventmachine

I'm trying to understand how to use evented web servers with a combination of async sinatra and EventMachine.

In the code below each request on '/' will generate a new async http request to google. Is there an elegant solution for detecting that a request is already ongoing and waiting for its execution ?

If I have 100 concurrent requests on '/', this will generate 100 requests to the google backend. It would be much better to have a way to detect there is already an ongoing backend request and wait for its execution.

thanks for the answer.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http-request'
require 'sinatra/async'


Sinatra.register Sinatra::Async

def get_data
  puts "Start request"
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://www.google.com").get
  http.callback { 
    puts "Request completed"
    yield http.response
  }
end

aget '/' do
  get_data {|data| body data}
end
```

**Update**

I actually discovered you can add several callbacks to the same http request. So, it's easy to implement:

```
class Request
  def get_data
    if !@http || @http.response_header.status != 0
      #puts "Creating new request"
      @http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://www.bbc.com").get
    end
    #puts "Adding callback"
    @http.callback do 
      #puts "Request completed"
      yield @http.response
    end
  end
end

$req = Request.new

aget '/' do
  $req.get_data {|data| body data}
end
```

This gives a very high number of requests per second. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use sinatra/async at all to make it evented, just run it with an evented server (Thin, Rainbows!, Goliath).

Take a look at [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) for an example of making multiple parallel requests without introducing spaghetti callback code:

```
require "em-synchrony"
require "em-synchrony/em-http"

EventMachine.synchrony do
  multi = EventMachine::Synchrony::Multi.new
  multi.add :a, EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://www.postrank.com").aget
  multi.add :b, EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://www.postrank.com").apost
  res = multi.perform

  p "Look ma, no callbacks, and parallel HTTP requests!"
  p res

  EventMachine.stop
end
```

And yes, you can run this inside your Sinatra action.

Also take a look at [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday/), specifically with EM adapter.

Comment: Puma and Unicorn are not evented servers.